# Modify unique attribute validation in Laravel

Tags: validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Trying to customize the error message for `unique` attribute. Tried changing my `validation.php`.

```php
$messages = [
    'custom' => [
        'email' => [
            'unique:users' => 'Oops, email is taken. Please try again!'
        ]
    ]
],
```

and I call the validation in `controller`:

```php
request()->validate([
    'email' => 'unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:3',
]);
```

And I still get this:

**The email has already been taken.**

Answer (score 0):

> using custom validator

You can create a custom validator and pass your messages into it

```php
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

For you this would mean

```php
$messages = [
    'email' => [
        'unique' => 'Oops, email is taken. Please try again!'
    ]
];


$rules = [
    'email' => 'unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:3',
];

$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('route/when/failed')
         ->withErrors($validator)
         ->withInput();
}
```

> using language file

In `resources/lang/{{language}}/validation.php` you can add

```php
'custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'unique' => 'Oops, email is taken. Please try again!',
    ],
]
```